# After the Tisha Bav fast tonight is over is one allowed to bathe because it is really the 11th of av?

Tags: tisha-bav

After the fast tonight, is one allowed to bathe, eat meat, launder clothes,etc? Because today is really the 10th of av so if I’m correct after midday today, the the destruction of the Beit Hamikdash stopped. So does the mourning continue until the midday of tomrow (11th of av) or does it stop because the 10th of av is over?

Answer (score 0):

> 4) When Tisha B'Av is a nidcheh, all restrictions are permitted immediately with the conclusion of the
>   fast on Sunday night [including bathing, shaving, music, etc...], with the exception of consuming wine
>   [other than for Havdala] and meat, which become permitted at daybreak of Monday morning.

**Source: http://www.shaaray-tefilah.org/weekly/halachos.pdf**

> If the ninth of Av falls on Shabbat, in which case the fast is delayed until the tenth, many of the restrictions applicable to the Nine Days end when the fast ends, and havdalah wine, music, bathing and haircutting are permitted. We do not eat meat or drink other wine until the next morning, however.

**Source: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/946845/jewish/Tisha-BAv-on-Shabbat-or-Sunday.htm**